# Storing private key and certificate (.pem) on android/iOS Keystore C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, keychain, client-certificates, android-keystore

I would like to create an asymmetric keypair on a client device (an iOS or Android phone running Xamarin.Forms) and create a Certificate Signing Request to be sent to an ASP.NET Core Restful API on a linux server running my database. To do so, I am using the Portable Bouncy Castle and the net core version on the API.

The CSR sent would be signed by a custom CA through the WebAPI and added to a Certificate Table on my DB, such that when the device sends a GET request, it can retrieve it (a one time activation key is used to authenticate the post of the csr as well as retrieval of the signed certificate).

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56118404/13819279), I have created a Private Key and CSR request, and converted the csr into a string that can be Posted to the API. When the API receives this, it places it in a text file that the script accesses to sign it using the CA certificate and CA key, creating a client-cert.pem file. This would be read as text and stored on the database so that the device can retrieve it.

After this point, I would like to store the Certificate and the Private Key in the device's Keystore, however as I am using Bouncy Castle to create the Keypair, it is in the type AsymmetricCipherKeyPair.

How would I go about storing these items in the Keystore such that it could be accessed to authenticate the client when connecting to the DB? I am currently unsure how Xamarin.Forms handles Keystores and how to store keys/certificates within them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can find a way to convert AsymmetricCipherKeyPair to string, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios) to store those keys in the KeyStore:

To save a value for a given key in secure storage:

```
try
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

To retrieve a value from secure storage:

```
try
{
  var oauthToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("oauth_token");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

Refer: [AsymmetricCipherKeyPair](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto/AsymmetricCipherKeyPair/-/php-asymmetriccipherkeypair-class-examples.html) and [/bouncy-castle-rsa-transforming-keys-into-a-string-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090624/bouncy-castle-rsa-transforming-keys-into-a-string-format)

Comment: My device would have the private key, public key in the CipherKeyPair as well as client certificate.pem but as a string. I assume that I do not need to store the public key as the client certificate contains this, so only the private key and cert are needed. Using the SetAsync method, do i use the client certificate as the key and the private key (one that no one should access except the app) as the value. What would i then do with the certificate to ensure someone couldnt access that private key by decrypting the stored value? Or is this value stored somewhere a device user could not access.

Comment: Yes, the value stored in the keystore can't be accessed by the user. Only the app can access the value by code.

Comment: @nevermore Do you have any source for the statement: "the value stored in the keystore can't bes accessed by the user"?